# Redirecting to login page if user enters root path

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, redirect

I've got a VB.net web app, and its start page is `http:\\<myServer>\<myApp>\webforms\login.aspx`

I'd rather they didn't have to enter this whole address. Is there a simple way to redirect my users to this page if they just enter the root i.e.  `http:\\<myServer>\<myApp>\` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have not changed the default pages in IIS, just setup a `default.aspx` on the root that redirects to the `login.aspx` page.

Comment: Won't that cause problems when I try to submit URL to Google. I'm sure they complain about pages that redirect immediately.

Comment: @Urbycoz - I thought that's what you wanted, an immediate redirect. You can avoid the redirect by using `Request.Transfer`.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought is to use URL Routing if you are using ASP.Net 3.5 or 4.0.  Here is a link - https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx  The page is specific to 3.5 SP 1, but there is another link on the page for 4.0.  So you might use  http:\\\login and it will route to http:\\\webforms\login.aspx.  HTH